# Email is not sending with Zipped attachment (csv file) in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, smtp, zip

I'm using the below code to send the mail with the zip attachment (CSV file),

```
     def send_mail()
    from = "admin@domainname.com"
    to = "user@domainname.com"
    cc = cc

    filename = "D:/test.zip"
    # Read a file and encode it into base64 format
    filecontent = File.read(filename).strip
    encodedcontent = [filecontent].pack("m")   # base64



    marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"

    body =<<EOF
This is a test email to send an attachement.
EOF

    # Define the main headers.
    part1 =<<EOF
From:  #{from}
To:  #{to}
Subject: Sending Attachement
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=#{marker}
--#{marker}
EOF

    # Define the message action
    part2 =<<EOF
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

#{body}
--#{marker}
EOF

    # Define the attachment section
    part3 =<<EOF
Content-Type: application/zip; name=\"#{"test.zip"}\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="#{"test.zip"}"

#{encodedcontent}
--#{marker}--
EOF

    mailtext = part1 + part2 + part3

    # Let's put our code in safe area
    begin
      Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
        smtp.sendmail(mailtext, from, to)

      end
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Exception occured: " + e
    end  
  end
```

But the emails are going as badmails.

I'm using Ruby-18.7 and Rails 2.3.2

Can you please let me If anything wrong in the code?

Thank you

Periyasamy

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I really cannot understand what you are doing and hence I should probably not be answering this question. However just in case you are completely wrong, try out the following:

The Mailer

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'email@example.com'

  def send_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

Now the mailer's view (.html.erb) file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.name %>.<br>
    </p>
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will generate a plain mail.

Finally adding attachment:

```
      def send_email(user)
        @user = user
        @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
        attachments['my_compressed_file.zip'] = File.read('path/to/file.zip')
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
      end
```

If you are still not able to send attachment, I'll suggest verify the file permission that you are attaching.

Note:

If the default ActionMailer fails, you can try alternative gems like [pony](https://github.com/benprew/pony)